# Getting previous month in shell script

Tags: bash, date, date-arithmetic

Right now, I'm using the following line of code to use my shell script to get the previous month as a two digit number:

```
lastMonth=$(date -d 'last month' +%m)
```

However, I'm wondering what this will return if I run it in January. I want to get 12 back for December, but I'm having a hard time testing how this will behave when I run the script in January. Anyway I can test this?

Comment: it will work as you expect. Good luck.

Comment: You can just set the current date to whatever you want with `date -s` and then test its behaviour.

Comment: To see `last month` for a specific date, you can use `date -d '2016-01-01 last month' +%m` which prints 12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a **ternary** like structure for doing it because you need to manage only one particular case that you already know (when lastMonth = 01)

```
lastMonth=$(date +%m)
[ $lastMonth -eq "01" ] && lastMonth=12 || ((lastMonth--))
```

---

First you need to test if you're in this special case with **test-condition**

```
[ $lastMonth -eq "01" ] #return true if you're in January, else false
```

Then the both [control operators](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Lists) **&&** (**AND**) and **||** (**OR**) are used like this

If the test return true :

```
[ true ] && lastMonth=12 || ((lastMonth--))
```

lastMonth is set to 12 but not decremented because an **OR** condition need **one** of his both part to be true for manage, left part return true so it'll not evaluate his right part

If the test return true :

```
[ false ] && lastMonth=12 || ((lastMonth--))
```

Right part of the **AND** will not be evaluated thanks to the [lazy evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation) and execute directly  right part of the **OR** condition, so decrement lastMonth in normal case

This is just one way to do it, like with if statements, numerical manipulation and so on.

Comment: `date` already computes this correctly, seems like an overkill with no upside.

Comment: I'm accepting this as an answer, but it went above and beyond what I needed. Thank you :)